# Word Create Several Document Properties in Quick Parts

Tags: microsoft-word

I am currently using Quick Parts > Document Properties to create fields that can update other parts of a Word document. I.e. if I change one field, all other similar fields will change as well. Problem is that I need a few dozen of these.

Is there a way to add more of these? Saving text to Quick Part Gallery does not work because I need this to be updated if it changes

Comment: "Saving text to Quick Part Gallery does not work because I need this to be updated if it changes" - can you describe what types of changes you envisage?

Comment: There are multiple fields and if the text of one changes, the text of all the other one changes automatically. Quick Parts Gallery is good for inserting snippets of text but if you make a change to it, it won't change what you have already inserted

Comment: thanks for the clarification. The things in the Document Properties dropdown are "sdt"s (Structured Document Tags) that display values of some of Word's built-in document property fields or from some special Cover Page Property fields. To make "properties" that work the same way (so that Word updates their values automatically), you have to use code, e.g. VBA, or you have to have to have SharePoint. Only the "properties" created in SharePoint appear on this list. sdts created using VBAare not on the list, but you can save them as Quick Parts and those *should* work the way you hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add Custom Properties**

- If the available document properties are not enough for you and you wish to add your own, open the `File` screen.
- From the current `info` screen, click on the `Properties` combo box on the right. Pick `Advanced Properties` (**Note**: This is Word 2013, it might look different than your Word version.)
- From the dialogue box, open tab `Custom`. Write a name you prefer or choose from the list beneath. From `Type`, choose `Text`. Then write the value that will be associated with the property you are creating. Now click `Add` and repeat this until you are done with every property you want to create. Click `OK` to confirm your changes.

(`Type` offers different format for the value; it could be a normal text, a date, a number, or a Yes/No option.)

**Use Custom Properties in Document**

- Like default document properties, your custom ones are treated as fields in Word, so from the Ribbon, choose `INSERT \ Quick Parts \ Field`.
- In the left list in the dialogue box, highlight `docProperty`. From the mid list, choose your document property and insert it with button `OK`.

**Add Fields as Written Codes**

- You don't need to open the dialogue box at `INSERT \ Quick Parts \ Field` if you remember the name of your property. From your document where you want to insert your property, hit `CTRL + F9`.
- In the empty greyed space between *special* curly parentheses, write `docproperty myproperty`, where `myproperty` is the name of your document property. Hit `F9` and then `SHIFT + F9` to display the value.

**What are Fields?**

- They are codes that represent variable contents in your document. Many inserted contents are basically fields, yet Word knows you like to see what these codes result in. If any document property (and eventually, any field) does not show updated results, highlight it and press `F9`.
- `F9` updates (on highlighted fields).
- `CTRL + A` then `F9` update every field (sometimes `CTRL + P` do the same).
- `SHIFT + F9` toggle code and results.
- `ALT + F9` toggle code and results for every field in the document.
- `CTRL + F9` insert field space to write code.

Comment: This answer is very detailed but it lacks to specify one important point, which makes it unfit for OP needs. The use of "Quick Parts > Document Properties" makes the document AUTO-UPDATE every instance of the property when any of the occurrencies is edited, and this reason is precisely why the OP is using this feature. The use of "Quick Parts > Field" (or the alternative equivalent sequence) inserts a text that is not to be edited. When you edit an occurrence nothing changes about the other ones. Plus, when you update the reference (e.g. pressing F9), the original value is restored.

Comment: (needed to split comment in two because it was too long). 
Of course you can modify the text by replacing the value inside the "Advanced properties" window, but it's not as much as handy.
Unfortunately, I am still looking for a different workaround, but still haven't found any solution without the use of VBA code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and was looking for the same solution.  I know how to create a fillable Word document, but what I needed was a way that someone could enter information in to an area and have it auto populate that same information several other places in the document. I have a 35 page grant agreement form that lists the person's name, grant dates, and other information several places throughout the agreement. Quick Parts > Document Properties would be a solution to my problem, but I too needed more fields than the 9 Doc Properties that are listed. I finally found the answer by mapping content controls with the XML Mapping Pane. I found a YouTube video that shows how to write the xml code in Microsoft Notepad and then apply it to work within my document. The video by Laura Leader can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtFhIqK0gec **Note, Laura got the information and credits the gregmaxey word tip pages website here: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/contentcontrol_enhancements_word_2013.html

Comment: With the `XML Pane` feature, that should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

### The only way I know of to add to these particular properties is through SharePoint.

I initiated a discussion on this some time ago on the Microsoft Answers site.
[XML Location of Document Property Content Controls Under Quick Parts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/xml-location-of-document-properties-in-quick-parts/589d1c93-4c44-4ba4-9594-84632f182f3f).

### The Document Properties Under Quick Parts are Special.

You *can* create Custom Document Properties as discussed in the other responses, but that is not the same as these Content Controls. These are special because they are mapped to the XML.

### The ones in the Quick Parts Document Properties menu can be Repurposed.

My page on these is [Repeating Data Using Document Property Content Controls and other Mapped Content Controls](http://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart). The primary focus of that page is on repurposing the 15 that come with Word in that menu.

These can be renamed and repurposed in a document or template. They are then used in different places by copying and pasting rather than from the menu.

### You Can Create Your Own Mapped Content Controls That Work the Same But Are Not In that Menu.

You can map your own [mapped Content Controls](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html) but these cannot be placed on that menu. *Link discusses what mapped Content Controls are and how to create your own.* Unfortunately, these custom mapped Content Controls cannot be exported to other documents through Building Blocks. They can be in a template, which if used as the basis for new documents or templates will retain these mapped controls.

For custom mapping, I generally use Greg Maxey's [Custom Content Control Insert Dialog](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/Content_Control_Custom_Insert_Dialog.html) or Graham Mayor's [Insert Content Control Add-In](https://www.gmayor.com/insert_content_control_addin.htm). Both are free and allow easy creation of Mapped CCs.

Comment: I came late to this question when I saw it referenced in another question and saw it still did not have an answer.